# Flutter json Decoding _TypeError (type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<dynamic, dynamic>')

Tags: arrays, json, api, flutter, decode

So this error I understand kind of what it is, and WHAT I need to do, but I don't understands HOW to do what I'm trying to do.

So I'm using an html api server-call, which returns a jsonEncoded List of Map objects.

The size of each list CAN (and will) change, so I cannot have a function that just checks and decodes the first few or something.  Also each Map object may contain different information, so I can't go making it parse statically.  I need to jsonDecode the entire list, and convert it BACK into a list of separate Map objects so I can use the information contained within the Map objects within the rest of my program.

For privacy reasons, I CANNOT provide an example of the type of object I'm receiving, (Or anything similar) and I apologize for the inconvenience, and increased difficulty of attempting to answer the question.

That said, I do know I just need to have a function that checks how many objects are in the list, splits the response.body into that many pieces, decodes each into a Map  object, and adds it to a list, or array.

Any information you can provide (Even if not specific code) would help, even if just telling me what commands I should look into.  (Preferably with an example of their syntax, but not mandatory of course).

If you need any information that I CAN provide, I'll be happy to do so. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you checked the question guidelines? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask If you can't share your code, then reproduce your problem with dummy code and share that here. without sharing any code, your chances of getting help are going to be low.

Comment: I can't share code, not can I create dummy code, which I'm aware is an issue.  The issue is that (For privacy reasons, non-disclosure clause) I cannot provide even a dummy copy of the server response.  However, the response I'm looking for is not specific code, but merely what kinds of commands I should be looking for.  I'm aware it's a generic question, but I'm looking for a generic response.  Thank you for your response though.

Comment: If that's the case, it's likely that your question will get downvoted and removed.

Comment: I can't see why.  If I had a very specific question, and did likewise, I could totally see why that would be the case.  This is NOT a specific question, but a generic one, as I'm looking for a place to start.  If people choose to downvote it, that's their choice, but there's no legitimate reason for it, and this DOES follow the community guidelines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your question is that we do not know even the general structure of your incoming data. We as a community do not need to know an actual example. Even faked data would suffice.

That being said, I will try to give you some examples of what your incoming data may be, and how you do what you are trying to do.

**Incoming JSON Object**

Lets say your incoming data looks like this:

```
{
  "data1": {
    "subdata1":"subvalue1",
    "subdata2":"subvalue2",
    "subdata3":3,
    "subdata4":{
      "subsubdata1":"subvalue1"
    }
  },
  "data2": {
    "subdata1":"subvalue1",
    "subdata2":"subvalue2",
    "subdata3":3,
    "subdata4":{
      "subsubdata1":"subvalue1"
    }
  }
}
```

In this case you can use jsonDecode, and still be able to count the keys and return the associated list of objects like this:

```
void consumeResponse(http.Response response) {
  // decode the entire response string
  final Map<String, dynamic> rawObject = jsonDecode(response.body);

  // count the records in the response
  final int recordCount = rawObject.keys.length;

  // create an array of the data in each top level object key (but you lose the top level key name)
  final List<dynamic> records = List<dynamic>.from(rawObject.values);
}
```

**Incoming JSON Array of Objects**

Lets say your json is actually in a json array already, and that your response looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "data1": {
      "subdata1":"subvalue1",
      "subdata2":"subvalue2",
      "subdata3":3,
      "subdata4":{
        "subsubdata1":"subvalue1"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "data2": {
      "subdata1":"subvalue1",
      "subdata2":"subvalue2",
      "subdata3":3,
      "subdata4":{
        "subsubdata1":"subvalue1"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Then you can accomplish the same thing with this function:

```
void consumeResponse(http.Response response) {
  // decode the entire response string. this will auto-magically produce a List<dynamic>
  final List<dynamic> records = jsonDecode(response.body);

  // count the records in the response
  final int recordCount = records.length;
}
```

**Incoming JSON Object with sub-list of data**

In some cases, you may have a list of results embedded in a wrapping json object that also contains some additional meta about your query. In that case your data might look like this:

```
{
  "meta": {
    "limit": 2,
    "offset": 1,
    "total": 47
  },
  "results": [
    {
      "data1": {   
        "subdata1":"subvalue1",
        "subdata2":"subvalue2",
        "subdata3":3,
        "subdata4":{
          "subsubdata1":"subvalue1"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "data2": {
        "subdata1":"subvalue1",
        "subdata2":"subvalue2",
        "subdata3":3,
        "subdata4":{
          "subsubdata1":"subvalue1"
        }
      }
    }
  ] 
}
```

In this case you may want to run the same function on the sub-list in the key `results`. You can use a similar function to do that too:

```
void consumeResponse(http.Response response) {
  // decode the entire response string
  final Map<String, dynamic> rawObject = jsonDecode(response.body);

  // create the List<dynamic> from the results list in the sub object
  final List<dynamic> records = rawObject['results'];

  // count the records in the response
  final int recordCount = records.length;
}
```

**Closing**

Hopefully, even though your question is quite vague, at least one of these scenarios is something that you can use. It is always better, if you can, to create some "mock data" and/or "mock code" that you can share. This community uses all available data to build their answers. The more data you provide us, the better of an answer you will get.

Comment: Thank you for actually taking the time to give me a place to start my research, rather than the alternative.  At the very least, with what you've given me I should be able to now get much farther in my code, and if I DO have a specific question, I'll be able to mock that up.  Again, thank you.